# Find driver remainings to complete Windows 10 1709 Update

Tags: windows, windows-10, drivers, windows-10-upgrade, windows-10-v1709

"Some apps need to be uninstalled" is shown in the update window, when trying to upgrade Windows 10 Pro to 1709. After pressing "uninstall and continue" it complains about the *Realtek PCIE Card Reader* being incompatible.

Problem is, it's a desktop PC, **without any card reader** in it. I have **no rtspstor.sys** driver installed anywhere on my system, nor do I have the usual Software installed with it in my program files folder, or any sign of it showing in the **device manager**.

- I tried installing the software non the less, only to uninstall it afterwards.
- I tried digging into the C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Panther logs, but did not find a clue to resolve the issue.
- I also tried to manually delete all traces of the card reader in the registry, which didn't help either.

How can I delete all remainings of the problem driver so I can update to 1709?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried uninstalling the **Moorefield** driver in the device manager, as this is a driver for my **ASUS ZenFone 2**, which was installed when I connected the mobile phone to my Windows-PC via USB.

After uninstalling this driver the update went on just fine!

The Windows-Update must have mistaken the driver for the *Realtek PCIE Card Reader*. Or the Moorefield driver contains parts of the Realtek driver. Either way, it works now!

Answer (score 3):

First of all, excuse me if my english is not perfect.
I had the same problem, but after some reasearch I figured it out.
I have a desktop, no card reader installed and still I've got the same message with manual uninstall required.

In C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Panther\setupact.log , I found this line:

CONX   Windows::Compat::Appraiser::SetupXmlOutputter::WriteProgramUninstallAction (480):   Manual uninstall required for rtspstor.sys|**518120dc41b4c4e8**.

After this, in the same directory I searched for

```
*APPRAISER*HumanReadable.xml
```

I opened a file with this name  z5VpIID0j0G7AEuX.4.0.2.51.3.8.0.0_APPRAISER_HumanReadable (XML document), and search for the number above, from the error log (**518120dc41b4c4e8**). I found this:

```
<Property Name="LongPathHash" Value="rtspstor.sys|518120dc41b4c4e8" />
<Property Name="LowerCaseLongPath" Value="d:\my documents - vechi\downloads\acer aspire maria\cardreader_realtek_6.1.7600.74_w7x86\driverbin_32bit\rtspstor.sys" />
```

It seems that an old driver stored on my hdd was the cause for all this trouble, so you must search your computer for this file, even if it isn't installed. 
Hope this will help others.

Regards.

Comment: This goes for 1803 as well. In my case I found a directory "C:\Windows\Drivers\EXE\Memory Card Reader Writer Driver (Realtek)", deleted it, and voila, the update would finally continue.

Answer (score 0):

Disconnect all external devices and go to your **Device Manager** to see if there is Realtek PCIE Card related device. If yes, uninstall it and then upgrade again.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. As I mentioned in my quenstion, I have no such entry in the Device Manager, though. I updated my question with some highlighting.